# remote tag not shown in local

Tags: git, git-tag

I am new to using git and tags. My team member ran the following commands:

```
git tag v1.27.1
git push origin v1.27.1
```

Now when I `git pull` and then run `git tag` in my environment, I expect to see a list of all the tags. I can see other tags that were pushed to repo in the similar way, but not this particular one.
I want to find out how/where did this tag get lost. How can I do this? What should be my approach?

Also, my team member who created the tag can see the tag on his machine when he runs `git tag`
Thanks!

Comment: As of 16 Jan 2019, `git pull` DOES fetch tags.
You just need to make sure that the machine where they are CREATED does `git push --tags`. Otherwise they will only exist on that machine!

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Unfortunately, `git pull` doesn't fetch tags by default.  You need to run `git fetch --tags`, and then you'll have them.

The default behavior of `git pull` and `git fetch` is to only retrieve tags that are directly accessible by the current references.  If any tags are not, then those are not fetched.  Passing `--tags` to `git fetch` tells git that you want them all, whether they're reachable by current references or not.

Comment: Then how do I see other tags added by my team members after I git pull?

Comment: `git tag` will give you a list of all the tags.  So `git tag | grep v1.27.1` should show the tag you were missing before.  If you still don't see it after fetching with `--tags`, then I'd check the remote repository with `git ls-remote <url-to-remote>` and check for the tag in the listing.  If it's not there, then it never made it to your central repository, so the developer needs to push it.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, git fetch --tags worked for me. I do not understand this completely though. When we say directly accessible by current references, what does current references mean?

Comment: This isn't entirely true, but references are pretty much branches.  In Git, branches are implemented using references, which pretty much means there's a file that contains a SHA1 pointing at the current tip of the branch.  When you commit to a branch, Git updates the reference to point to the new tip.  So if you have a tag that is directly reachable from a branch, then Git will pull in the tag as well.  I hope that makes sense.  It does get a bit abstract. :-)

Comment: If anyone is looking for further information, [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) site goes into more detail.

Comment: Apparently `git push` has the same default behavior; so, if a tag is missing (that was added to a local repro), make sure `git push --tags` is called for that repro.

Comment: @mike You might want to take a look at the [push.followTags](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pushfollowTags) config option.  I use it to help push up tags without me having to do a separate `git push --tags`. :-)